# Not able to pass value to another class

Tags: ios, swift

I want to append a certain "id" to an api. This is the initial portion of how I make the API call in my viewController..

```
func myAPICall() {
     APIHelper(API: WebServices.getAllOrganizations as NSString, json: bodyStr as NSString, 
      methodType: Constants.Get_Method as NSString....) 
}
```

Now, `WebServices.getAllOrganizations` is defined elsewhere, in a swift file like so...

```
public class WebServices {

static let getAllOrganizations: String = "organization/getAllOrganizationDetails

}
```

---

- MY ATTEMPT TO PASS THE ID TO THE SWIFT FILE :

---

To pass the value, I assigned it to a global variable like so...

`ArrayData.shared.plantIDForOrganization =  Int("\(dic["id"]!)")!`

And further, I changed my swift file to this...

```
public class WebServices {

static let getAllOrganizations: String = "organization/getAllOrganizationDetails/\(ArrayData.shared.plantIDForOrganization)"                                  

}
```

But by doing this, the value is not properly passed to the API. A `0` is passed to the API instead of the actual `id` number.

What could be a more efficient way of passing value from my viewcontroller to the swift file..?

Comment: What is present `dict["id"]`? Is it a String? How is it assigned?
I find the implementation to add a resource id to a global variable just to make an API call a bit wierd..  Why not just have 
`func myAPICall(id: String){ //append id to URL here }`

Comment: `dict["id"]?` is an integer value like 543 for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When is `ArrayData.shared.plantIDForOrganization` initialized, and when does `WebServices.getAllOganizations` get its value? Once the latter is set, it won't "react" to changes in `plantIDForOrganization`.

I suggest you change this to a computed property, like so:

```
public class WebServices {

    static var getAllOrganizations: String {
        return "organization/getAllOrganizationDetails/\(ArrayData.shared.plantIDForOrganization)"
    }
}
```

Also, try to eliminate thos force-unwrapping from your code.

Comment: thanks @Gereon....Would you maybe explain in a line or two as to why this worked and why my code didn't...?

Comment: When accessing `WebServices.getAllOrganizations`, the value is derived at that moment(computed property). What happens in your previous code is, the value for the variable gets set and is never changed. Making it a computed property solves it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass a parameter use a `static` method instead:

```
public class WebServices {
    static func getAllOrganizations(id: String) -> String { "organization/getAllOrganizationDetails/\(id)" }
}
```